# What is the correct form of the NHEK metric?

Tags: general-relativity

I've noticed that in different articles people are writing the near horizon extreme Kerr metric (NHEK) in different forms.

Original Kerr/CFT correspondence article by Guica et. al. follows Bardeen-Horowitz 'Extreme Kerr Throat' article, in which NHEK metric (line element) is given by

$$ds^2=2GJ\Omega^2\left[-(1+r^2)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{1+r^2}+d\theta^2+\lambda^2(d\phi+rdt)^2\right]$$

Compere, and some other authors say that the NHEK line element is

$$ds^2=2GJ\Omega^2\left[-r^2dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{r^2}+d\theta^2+\lambda^2(d\phi+rdt)^2\right]$$

I am confused. I followed Bardeen and Horowitz derivation of the NHEK metric, and got the same result. Second metric is simplified considerably (especially when solving Lie derivative).

Why the difference, and can I use which ever I want?

EDIT:

Links to articles:

Kerr/CFT (Guica et. al.): http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4266 (eq 3.7)

Kerr Throat (Bardeen-Horowitz): http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905099 (eq 2.9)

The Kerr/CFT Correspondence and its Extensions (Compere): http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2012-11/ (eq 25 with parameters from eq 37)

Yet Another Realization of Kerr/CFT Correspondence (Matsuo et. al.): http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4272 (eq 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look, in Bardeen-Horowitz, how you get $2.9$ from $2.6$ (these correspond to your 2 expressions), from $2.7$ and $2.8$

Comment: But if we don't do the redefinitions, we don't get the extra global translation symmetry. 2.7 and 2.8 are global coordinates. Aren't we loosing information if we take the simplified version?

Comment: The $2$ metrics $(2.6)$ and $(2.9)$ are equivalent (it is the same manifold described with different parameters), so there is no "simplified version". Maybe some global symmetries are more manifest with $2.9$, but  $2.6$ has  these global symmetries too.

Comment: What's kinda confusing is that Guica, says that (they have slightly different parametrization, but if you set $r\to 1/y$ you get the same throat solution 2.6 as Bardeen) those coordinates cover only part of the NHEK (not global coordinates). And that's why we go to the 2.9. What I'm worrying is whether my calculations will be different because of that :\

Comment: Correct, see also this [paper](http://www.ift.unesp.br/users/nastase/AdS-CFTnotes.pdf) pages $16,17,18$, the Poincaré Patch only covers a part of the manifold Ads, and this is different from the metrics in global coordinates. Now, your calculations are correct, for sure, you have only to check the domain of definition  if you want to draw physical conclusions.

Comment: It is the same problem when you use standard Schwarzschild coordinates, as long as you are in the domain $r> R_s$, you are coherent. If you want to extend the domain, you have to take the [Kruskal-Szekeres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) coordinates which cover the "entire spacetime manifold".

Comment: Ok, so I can use the 'simpler' metric, but I need to be careful with the definitions of the coordinates (like looking at infinity etc.)?

Comment: Sure. But the entire discussion is more subtle : see page $5$ and first half of page $6$ in Bardeen